# Move lines in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to replicate [TextMate](http://macromates.com)'s *move selection* command in Vim.
I've come up with this:

```
map <C-D-Up> ddkP
map <C-D-Down> ddp
vmap <C-D-Up> dkP
vmap <C-D-Down> dp
```

Single lines work just as expected. But visual mode isn't perfect.

I want it to keep (or reselect) the selection in visual mode, so that I can move the selection multiple times easily. I found `gv` but that doesn't work, as it doesn't select the moved lines but something further down the document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yep nice thing. Take a look at this screencast http://vimcasts.org/episodes/bubbling-text/. It solves exactly this problem.

Comment: Avoid using map, use nnoremap or vnoremap instead, it can avoid issue with recursive mappings.